# Onde foi parar o demonstrador do _POST do console no novo firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Até eu atualizar o firefox no meu PC (Ubuntu 16.4) o console demonstrava em um lugar `'params'` (Não tenho mais certeza se era 'params' ou 'post') o que eu havia enviado pelo método `post`, agora essa aba não exibe nada, onde que essa função foi parar no novo firefox ? 
Estou com a versão 57.0b3 64-bits.

Answer (score 1):

Se for o "params" esta aqui:

Network > Você seleciona a pagina que fez o envio > ao lado tem a aba "Params"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse sim, mas esse é horrivel de usar, eu queria ver o que aconteceu no console, o params retorna vazio la sempre, talvez seja alguma configuração, mas não to achando

Comment: Tem estas "caixinhas" (All, HTML, CSS, ...) as vezes você desmarcou algumas destas, ai para de apresentar algumas coisas.

Comment: Tudo que tem pra estar marcado ta marcado, vo reverter a att acho mesmo tendo ficado mais bonito kk